# Update Select with where & CONCAT issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table with another table data after concating two columns It shows errors.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax

Table 1: orders
Table 2: users

I am trying to update orders table field `name` by comparing a field with `user_id` in orders table.

The `user_id` is linked to users table. I am trying to concat `first_name` & `last_name` and update the `name` in orders table.

```
UPDATE orders SET 
(name =
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as full_name
FROM users u
WHERE u.first_name IS NOT NULL OR u.first_name <> '' );
```

The condition goes like this.

If any id present in `user_id` in orders table it should check `users` table`id` and select & concat `first_name` & `last_name` and update the order table.

If no `user_id` in orders table the field should be updated with `NONE`.

Its complicate for me to do it via Query. I can do that in PHP but its not recomended. Can some one help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a user_id column on the orders table to join to, you could try this:

```
UPDATE orders o SET o.name = 
   IFNULL((SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS full_name 
           FROM users u 
           WHERE u.user_id = o.user_id 
           AND u.first_name IS NOT NULL 
           AND u.first_name <> ''), 'NONE');
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'o.user_id' in 'where clause' it is not taking the orders table column

Comment: I was going on the assumption you had a user_id column on the orders table to join to, otherwise how do you expect to pull out the name of user that corresponds to the order?   :)

Comment: in order table i have `user_id` and in user table i have `id` this both fields can join

Comment: So change the WHERE clause to be WHERE u.id = o.user_id  :)

Comment: i did it myself but after that only i saw the error `o.user_id ` :(